# TListView Caption-Cell of last row doesn't get colored

Tags: vcl, ownerdrawn, tlistview, c++builder-xe7

I have been working with VCL for a couple months now, and could solve all my problems by googling, but this one got me stuck.
I want to color a row in a TListView whenever the subItem at index 7 of that row does not contain a certain text (see code below). It all works well, except that the caption-cell (furthest to the left) of the last row does not get colored. I tried a couple hacks (e.g. enabling and then disbaling the ListView when drawing an item), but I didn't find one that doesn't break other stuff on the form (e.g. timers).
Also, after I click on the cell, it does get colored...
I'm using XE7 (C++Builder) on Windows 7.
All suggestions are appreciated ;)

```
void __fastcall TBackupManagerForm::OverviewListViewCustomDrawItem(TCustomListView *Sender, TListItem *Item, TRect &Rect, TOwnerDrawState State)
{
    if ((*Item->SubItems)[7] != "someText") {
    Sender->Canvas->Brush->Color = clRed;
  }
  else {
    Sender->Canvas->Brush->Color = clWindow;
  }
  TRect r, rt;
  r = Item->DisplayRect(drBounds);
  Sender->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);
  r.Right = r.Left + (*OverviewListView->Columns)[0]->Width;
  rt = r;
  rt.Left += 5;
  rt.Top += 1;
  UnicodeString s = Item->Caption;
  Sender->Canvas->TextRect(rt, s, TTextFormat()<<tfSingleLine<<tfEndEllipsis);

  for (int i = 0; i < Item->SubItems->Count; i++) {
    ListView_GetSubItemRect(Sender->Handle, Item->Index, i+1, LVIR_BOUNDS,&rt);
    s = (*Item->SubItems)[i];
    Sender->Canvas->TextRect(rt, s, TTextFormat()<<tfSingleLine<<tfEndEllipsis);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
(Answering comments here because not enough rep :P)

@PaulMcCarthy Yeah, that seemed weird to me too...

@RemyLebeau Thanks for the suggestions, I implemented them.

Also, I managed to get it drawn properly by making an extra call to `OverviewListView->Refresh()` from outside `CustomDrwaItem`, but it still bugs me that it didn't work without it (pun somewhat intended).

Comment: I'm surprised the line below is not giving you an error:
     r.Right = r.left + OverviewListView->Columns->Items[i+1]->Width;

When it reaches the last column, i+1 would be referencing something that does not exist. (or am I reading it wrong)

Comment: For that matter, I don't generally recommend using the `OnDrawItem` event, either, especially not to draw all columns in one go.  I prefer to use the `On(Advanced)CustomDrawItem` and `On(Advanced)CustomDrawSubItem` events instead. They offer more control over drawing at various stages, and you can draw the columns individually only when actually needed.

Comment: Rather than calculating the column rectangles manually and risk going out of bounds, you should use [`ListView_GetSubItemRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775004.aspx) instead.